# How to recognize touch events and control a script object inside UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, controls, touch

Situation:
I have an UIView with an UIWebView in it.
When the `viewDidLoad` the Javascript Object inside the `UIWebView` is called (Microsoft Seadragon AJAX JS).

*For your Understanding*:
Seadragon loads a specified megapixel image(JPEG) and in a Desktop Browser like Firefox i can Zoom into the image and I can drag the crop for example from the middle to the left.

In the iPhone Simulator (for iPad) only the Zooming Function is working on one single tap but when i try to drag the crop (with left mouse button click and holding it) I'm dragging the whole `UIWebView` but not the crop of course!

Is that feature which the simulator isn't able to handle or what's yout solutin guys?

***Special Thanks!!***

P.S.: It's a bit jiggling when the zooming function of Seadragon is called. Is that authentic to the real performance of the iPad or does the simulator not have the power as the iPad has?

Comment: In many cases, the simulator will be faster than the device.  The simulator is not emulated, it is running native code with the full resources (ram,video card,cores) of the desktop system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent scrolling in your UIWebView by including this javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);

function touchMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

With scrolling disabled, your javascript should receive normal mousemove events.

Comment: Ok, and what should be equal to element? Should this be inserted in loadHTMLstring method of UIWebView?
Thanks!

Comment: Whoops.  Copy-paste error.  You can addEventListener on the document object.  I edited my answer.